# Is there an app for Android that can display messages as reminders for specific incoming calls?

Tags: android

I would like to be able to give myself reminders of what to say when a specific numbers (contacts) call in. For example if Joe calls in, I'm reminded that he has a peanut allergy or something. What apps can do this? I have Tasker.